# Accessing restriction from owl-superclass with Apache Jena

Tags: jena, owl

I have this owl-file. #indelivers is a subclass of #ipInDelivers. What I want to find out is how to find what #isPartOfMibDef resource this class has, in this case #IP-MIB.

```
<owl:ObjectProperty rdf:about="#isPartOfMibDef"/>

<owl:ObjectProperty rdf:about="#hasSyntax"/>

<owl:Class rdf:about="#Counter32">
    <rdfs:subClassOf rdf:resource="#SYNTAX"/>
</owl:Class>

<owl:Class rdf:about="&owl;Thing"/>

<owl:Class rdf:about="#mibObjects">
    <rdfs:subClassOf rdf:resource="&owl;Thing"/>
</owl:Class>

<owl:Class rdf:about="#IP-MIB">
    <rdfs:subClassOf rdf:resource="#mibDefs"/>
</owl:Class>

<owl:Class rdf:about="#ipInDelivers">
    <owl:equivalentClass>
        <owl:Class>
            <owl:intersectionOf rdf:parseType="Collection">
                <owl:Restriction>
                    <owl:onProperty rdf:resource="#hasSyntax"/>
                    <owl:allValuesFrom rdf:resource="#Counter32"/>
                </owl:Restriction>
                <owl:Restriction>
                    <owl:onProperty rdf:resource="#isPartOfMibDef"/>
                    <owl:allValuesFrom rdf:resource="#IP-MIB"/>
                </owl:Restriction>
            </owl:intersectionOf>
        </owl:Class>
    </owl:equivalentClass>
    <rdfs:subClassOf rdf:resource="#mibObjects"/>
</owl:Class>

<owl:Class rdf:about="#aliases">
    <rdfs:subClassOf rdf:resource="&owl;Thing"/>
</owl:Class>

<owl:Class rdf:about="#indelivers">
    <rdfs:subClassOf rdf:resource="#aliases"/>
    <rdfs:subClassOf rdf:resource="#ipInDelivers"/>
</owl:Class>
```

The code I have so far is this:

```
String NS = "http://namespace.com/owl#";
InputStream is = FileManager.get().open(this.owlPath);
OntModel ontology = ModelFactory.createOntologyModel(OntModelSpec.OWL_MEM_MICRO_RULE_INF,null);
    ontology.read(is,"");

Reasoner reason = ReasonerRegistry.getOWLMicroReasoner();
InfModel info = ModelFactory.createInfModel(reason,ontology);

OntClass alias = this.ontology.getOntClass(NS+"indelivers");
OntClass superClass = alias.getSuperClass();
```

I've tried accessing most get- and list functions in the superClass, but I can't seem to find the #isPartOfMibDef anywhere

Answer (score 0):

Your namespace should be:

```
String NS = "http://namespace.com/owl#";
```

Comment: Yes, I know, it was just a typo in the OP.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me. My owl class "session" does not have an intersection though.

```
OntClass cl1 = model.getOntClass(nsPrefix + "session");
    OntClass cl = cl1.getSuperClass();
    for (StmtIterator i = model.listStatements(cl, null, (RDFNode) null); i.hasNext(); ) {
        Statement stmt = i.nextStatement();
        logger.info(" - " + PrintUtil.print(stmt));
    }
```